# Copy data from a workbook with sheets.codename

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a combobox with 9 sheetnames.
When I select a name the macro finds the sheet.
However, I cant copy a range to my active worksheet,
its gives the error 438 on the row "wb.blad.CodeName.Range("A1:J80").Select" 
All the worksheets have a codename.
I can't find the solution. Here is mij code;

```
Private Sub discipline_Change()
blad = databaas.discipline.Text
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Genius\Desktop\db.xlsx")

'wb.Worksheets.blad.Range("B1:J80").Copy sh2.Range("B1")

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.CodeName = blad Then
        wb.blad.CodeName.Range("A1:J80").Select
        Selection.Copy
        sh2.Range("A1").Select
        sh2.Paste
    End If
Next

ActiveWindow.Close
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `ws` instead of `wb.blad.CodeName`?

Comment: Is `sh2` in the Workbook you opened?  If it is in another workbook, then you need to specify the workbook.  Codenames don’t work across workbooks.  Once you open the other workbook, it becomes the active workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wb.blad.CodeName.Range("A1:J80").Select` doesn't make sense.

Use `ws.Range("A1:J80").Select`